# How to log custom data in flask service using python Logger

Tags: python, flask, logging

I have `flask` service and I'm trying to add some custom fields in Logger

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17558764/timeline)

and implemented this

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging
import json


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()

formatter = """{"name":,%(name)s, "module_name": %(module)s,"pid": %(process)d,"level": %(levelno)d,\
"level_name": %(levelname)s, "msg": %(message)s, "data": %(data_)s, "time": %(asctime)s,\
"src": { "file": %(pathname)s, "line": %(lineno)d }, "function": %(funcName)s}"""

formatter = logging.Formatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

adapter = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger=logger, extra=dict(data_=0))


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/home', methods=["GET"])
def home():
    adapter.info("OK", extra=dict(data_=0))
    return "OK"


@app.route('/user', methods=["POST"])
def user_check():
    req_data = json.loads(request.data)
    adapter.info("User check request received", extra=dict(data_=23))
    return "Check Complete"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Whenever I hit the service `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user` I'm getting log as below

`{"name":,__main__, "module_name": app,"pid": 433712,"level": 20,"level_name": INFO, "msg": User check request received, "data": 0, "time": 2020-12-19 12:19:13,782,"src": { "file": app.py, "line": 43 }, "function": user_check}`

If you see the data is not updated with value passed in `extra` parameter, I can't get my head around it why it is not updating or

is there better way to add custom fields into Logger?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with `logger.info()` instead of `adapter.info()`.

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcoa9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcoa9.png) attaching the screenshot. Commented out `req_data = json.loads(request.data)`.